# Regex Replace [*]

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
something.something[0].somethingelse[21].blah
```

I want to replace all the [*] section with an empty string so that I end up with a string like this:

```
something.something.somethingelse.blah
```

(I'm doing this in Python if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', 'something.something[0].somethingelse[21].blah')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'\[[0-9]+\]')
s = 'something.something[0].somethingelse[21].blah'

print p.sub('', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
\[\d*\]
```

and replace with ""